# I am trying to get records from two tables with laravel using WhereAs

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to get records of users from two tables..SALES TABLE & USER TABLE.

But from the SALES table, i want to get only sales of the current month for each of the user.

I have merged the tables already from the model, but when i try to get the record using this code it keeps pulling the sales for both current month and previous month from SALES table..

```
$myrecords = User::whereHas('sales', function($query) {
              $query->whereMonth('sales.created_at', Carbon::now()->month); 
}) 
->get();
```

Please what am i doing wrong here

Comment: It does current AND last, or just last month?

Comment: i just to pick the sales from the SALES table..but only for current month only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$users = User::whereHas('sales', function($query) {
    $query->whereMonth('sales.created_at', Carbon::now()->month);  
})->get();
```

This will get all users who had sales last month, so if you try to say ->with('sales'), it will get all users who had sales last month, and all other sales they ever had.

If you are looking to [limit the relation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads), you need to do the following.

```
User::with(['sales' => function ($query) {
    $query->whereMonth('created_at', Carbon::now()->month);  
}])->get();
```

That will give you all users with only sales that occurred this month.

Comment: your second solution provides this.  mb_strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Comment: Sorry, forgot the array  in the with(), try now

Comment: Finished now. :)

Comment: ok let me check pls..sorry for the delay in response